# Pass data from component to service 1. Service 2 depends on service 1. Service 2 data to component

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-services

I am creating a weather application.

I have `view.component`, `coord.service`, `weather.service`.

I have `view.component` for user input. I want to pass input from component to `coord.service` which makes an API call and returns coordinates. The coordinates should be passed to `weather.service` which also makes an API call and returns an Observable back to `view.component` for rendering into HTML. I cannot figure out/understand how to make this happen.

`view.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-view',
  templateUrl: './view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view.component.css']
})

export class ViewComponent implements OnChanges {
  alerts: any;
  currData:any = {};

  @Input() location: string;

  coordinate = [];

  constructor(public weatherService: WeatherService) { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // pass location to coord.service -> i don't know what to do from here
    //this.weatherData(this.coordinate);
  }

  weatherData(coord: Array<number>) {
    this.weatherService.getWeatherInfo(coord).subscribe((data) => {
     // do something with data and make it render
    });
  }
```

`coord.service`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CoordinateService {

  readonly coord_API = ""

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) {  }

  getCoordinates(location : string) {
    return this.http.get(this.coord_API.replace("*", location)).pipe(
      tap(_ => console.log("recieved geoData")),
      catchError(err => {throw "GEO ERROR: " + err})
    )
  }
}
```

`weather.service`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeatherService {
  readonly weather_api : string = "";
  coordinates : [] = [];
  // I need to pass in input from component to coordService
  constructor(public http : HttpClient, public coordinateService : CoordinateService) {  }

  getWeatherInfo(coordinates : Array<number>, type="daily") {
    return this.http.get(this.weather_api).pipe(
      tap(_ => console.log('got data')),
      catchError(err => {throw "WE. ERR : " + err})
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Inject the weather service instance in coord.service constructor and pass the data to it. Just like you have added httpClient service in your both services. You don't need to inject both services as each other dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your component should aggregate the services and make the calls.

```
constructor(
  public weatherService: WeatherService,
  public coordsService: CoordinateService,
) { }

weatherData() {
  this.coordsService.getCoordinates('your param').pipe(
    switchMap(coords => this.weatherService.getWeatherInfo(coords))
  ).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}
```

Services are providers that can be injected to anything in Angular. They should have a single purpose : the components should then be able to use them and combine them.

`switchMap` is an RxJS operator.

RxJS is a library widely used by Angular, that enables [reactive programming](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-introduction-to-functional-reactive-programming-in-redux-b0c14d097836). When you make an HTTP call, you create an observer, that is created through the `subscribe` keyword. That creates a stream, in which the data is immutable.

RxJS allows you to use operators to manipulate the stream. You have [a lot of operators](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/) to choose from.

In the case of `switchMap` : this is an operator that allows you to switch the stream for another one. This means that first you request the coordinates, and then use `switchMap` to request the weather, with the result of the first http call.

You have several operators for that, like `mergeMap`, `flatMap` ... But `switchMap` should always be the first choice, because it cancels any pending request if the observable is getting observed again. That means the user will cancel the pending request if he clicks on the button several times in a row, resulting in fewer http calls.

Comment: This is the much better approach to combine & share data between two services.

Comment: I understand that in component i pass input to coordService. Can you help me understand what this is `switchMap(coords => this.weatherService.getWeatherInfo(coords))`; `coords` is massaged data from coord_API. How would I make sure correct values are passed into coords?

Comment: @AlbinVinoy I have explained the concept in an edit, feel free to read it !